# Rewriting URLs in ASP.NET/C#

Tags: asp.net, url

How can I use the below code to call an account as

http://www.domain.ext/madcoder

instead of

http://www.domain.ext/index.aspx?key=madcoder

As my `madcoder` is my primary search key to fetch databse

I found the following code but couldn't understand how to use it. Anybody please help me.

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="?p={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

EDIT 1

I tried modifying my web.config file in the below way which is giving me error

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    </system.web>
    <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.aspx?key={R:1}" />
    </rule>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .net 4.0 it can be MUCH easier.

[.net 4 Webforms Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.aspx?key={R:1}" />
```

About the match/replace tags: the match-url is applied on the url *after* the domain slash (in your case, after `http://www.domain.ext/`). The parentheses are for grouping and catching, so `([^/]+)` will match anything not containing a slash, right after the domain. It may contain a trailing slash, but anything else is currently disallowed.

The rewrite action can contain a literal string, but can also contain `{R:xxx}` references, which refer to anything you caught in the parentheses earlier. In this case, the string `madcoder`.

Comment: where should I write this action code. Is that in web.config file or any other file?

Comment: @Mad coder: These rules go into web.config. You can edit them most easily in IIS directly, just click the URL Rewrite icon. It has a GUI that makes editing (and testing!) rewrite rules a breeze.

Answer (score 1):

try this this work successfully
   write following code in web config

```
 <system.web>
        <urlMappings enabled="true">
          <add url="~/Index" mappedUrl="Index.aspx?key={R:1}"/>

        </urlMappings>
    </system.web>
```

in c# write following code

```
Response.redirect("~/index")
```

or else u can also pass your value