# How to rewrites URLs in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been using Helicon to rewrite my URLs and they are in a file htaccess (no dot).  The rewrite goes something like:

`RewriteRule /e-commerce /e-commerce.asp [I,U]`

I have read a few answers, starting with [How to Determine the Installed ASP.NET Version of Host from a Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468/how-to-determine-the-installed-asp-net-version-of-host-from-a-web-page). I ran the page, and it displayed 2.0.50727.3643

A little history so maybe one can be gentle.  I was a Microsoft Frontpage MVP, but disliked their Frontpage Server Extensions (FPSE).  Some hosting companies are still using them, but the last ones were back in 2002.

I was a Microsoft guy.  So I went with Microsoft servers and started using ASP includes.  Then I came across Helicon - and used it for 4-5 yrs.  Some of my sites are having no issues, but some of them are.  And my new prices along with new hardware for credit card processing is out and I really need help (BTW, I looked for an e-commerce section but found nothing if y'all have one, I'll be more than happy to help).

I do not even know what is the file name I should be using and the information that goes in there.

[Rename a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp)

[How to rename a file in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150333/how-to-rename-a-file-in-net)

[Rewriting URLs in ASP.NET/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495774/rewriting-urls-in-asp-net-c)

[Custom Url Rewriting in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306878/custom-url-rewriting-in-asp-net)

I have seen several file names but I do not know which one to use.  I am sure there is a question out there that matches mine, but after looking for several hours, I am hoping some of the experts will be able to help me out.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a classic ASP site or an ASP.net site?

Comment: It is classic asp using Helicon but I think that is causing problems which is why I would like to rewrite the URLs in AsP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to URLRewriter.Net. It's very easy to integrate into asp.net project. Instead of IIS level it implements url rewriting at asp.net level.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I need.  Of course, it is speaking about files that I have heard of (web.config)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I ran out of time & space.
(Start at web.config)
This though talks about Add rewriter HttpModule: - which I have not heard of.

And then I go back to the web.config:
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <rewriter>
    <rewrite url="/tags/(.+)" to="/tagcloud.aspx?tag=$1" />
    </rewriter>

<!-- end snippet -->

I am not sure if tags folder is being rewritten to /tagcloud.aspx?tag=$1
I just need a lot of URLs rewritten 
from:
www.example.com/internet/rates.aspx
www.example.com/rates.aspx
to
www.example.com/internet/rates
www.example.com/rates

Comment: It's tricky getting the two things to play nice together since ASP.Net is completely different than classic ASP. I did run across this article that may help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2012/12/31/using-classic-asp-and-url-rewrite-for-dynamic-seo-functionality.aspx  There is also a URL Rewriting module for IIS at: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite   Oh, and don't know if you remember me, but I was an FP MVP from '97 till the end.

Comment: That might be why I remember your name.  The http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite is that that program that you sign into the website to re-write the URLs?

Comment: I already worked it out with the ISO to pay residuals to my family when I pass away.  Have had a few health issues and not possibly prostate cancer.  So that is why I want to start with Interns and hopefully we will be able to build a good business.